# Publish VS2010 Solution to ISS(local) using Jenkins MSBuild Plugin command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins successfully build my job using MSBuild plugin(framework 4.0) with this Command Line Arguments

```
/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PackageTempDir=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Example_Jenkins
```

The problem is that the solution isn't published in the given directory(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Example_Jenkins) it only goes in the jenkins workspace folder. I even tried changing the command line arguments to commands like in web publish still files are not being deployed in the given folder.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it not in the correct way. The correct way is described, for example, here: http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

```
msbuild Website.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Debug;PublishDestination=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Example_Jenkins" /t:PublishToFileSystem
```

PS I don't think it's so much jenkins related :)

Comment: It is jenkins related. I am using the jenkins plugin. I am building a sln not a csproj

Comment: Then, just replace csproj with sln,  it will work, just checked.

Comment: I did. It just keeps on being sent to the package folder

Comment: But have you edited the "Publish" part ? Can you show me how your "Target Name="PublishToFileSystem"" looks like?

Comment: is that on the csproj? I tried adding something like that in the commandline and nothing happens